# Virtualbox on Ubuntu Server 22.04 problem

Tags: virtualbox

I installed Virtualbox from standart repos on Ubuntu Server.
Virtualbox version is 6.1.32, which is supporting kernel version 5.16+ (my version is 5.15.0-27-generic).
Then I installed phpvirtualbox from their github, apache and etc.
So, after installation, I have no vboxwebsrv service, and likely because of this, phpvirtualbox fails to [start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UMpo.png).

Some output:

```
~$ sudo service vboxwebsrv restart
Failed to restart vboxwebsrv.service: Unit vboxwebsrv.service not found.
~$ sudo service vboxdrv start
Failed to start vboxdrv.service: Unit vboxdrv.service not found.
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR (as root):

```bsh
# 1. enable virtualbox
echo "LOAD_VBOXDRV_MODULE=1" >> /etc/default/virtualbox
service virtualbox restart

# 2. enable vboxweb-service
echo "VBOXWEB_USER=vbox" >>  /etc/default/virtualbox
cp /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxweb-service.sh /etc/init.d/vboxweb-service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo service vboxweb-service restart
```

Explanation:

1. In the Ubuntu-provided package, the startup script is `/etc/init.d/virtualbox`, which states (around line 44):

```bsh
if [ "$LOAD_VBOXDRV_MODULE" != 1 ]; then
        log_success_msg "virtualbox disabled; edit /etc/default/virtualbox"
        exit 0
fi
```

So `LOAD_VBOXDRV_MODULE` must be set to `1` in /etc/default/virtualbox.

However, this will load the virtualbox kernel modules, **but it will not start the web service** (which is required for phpvirtualbox to work...)

2. The startup script for vboxweb-service is present in the package, but no installed, so you have to manually copy the script to `/etc/init.d`, then reload systemd (otherwise you'll get an error like `Failed to start virtualbox-websrv.service: Unit virtualbox-websrv.service not found.`) and finally you can start vboxweb-service

Moreover, you have to indicate which user will be running the VM's (the `VBOXWEB_USER` directive, but this is already explained in the documentation of phpvirtualbox)